# Do I get double the conquest points when crafting?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

With the new patch there are new items to craft. For some of those items(war supplies) you can get conquest points.

If I craft a war supply and it crits(that means I get 2 war supplies instead of 1) do I also get double the conquest points?

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: idk. Maybe you can improve your question format, adding paragraphs, bold, italic and stuff that make the question be easier to read and objective.

Comment: @Damek Probably just someone not understanding the question or not liking the game. The question is fine so dont worry too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from experience you only get Conquest points for each completed craft (regardless of whether it yields an extra item via crit).  [This source confirms.](http://remnantsofhope.com/boards/index.php?/topic/13963-conquest-week-two/?p=149452)